# How to putExtra and getExra the string from any other activity? like a global variable?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent

I want to make each button on the main activity to putExra a different string unique to the button. Then, to access those values using getExtra. This is how I have implemented. It does not work. Please show me the correct implementation.

these lines are in the 1st activity

```
   public Intent writePatientData = new Intent();
   public void onClick(View view){
                    writePatientData.putExtra("SYSTEM", "Cardiovascular system");
                    startEntringPatientData();
   }
```

and this is in the 2nd activity

```
textView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("SYSTEM"));
```

Comment: does you call startActivity() method?

Comment: No. Outside the startActivity

Comment: you are not passing intent context on your startActivity method. check answer below.

Answer (score 0):

For passing data to another activity:

```
public Intent writePatientData = new Intent();
   public void onClick(View view){
                    writePatientData.putExtra("SYSTEM", "Cardiovascular system");
                    startEntringPatientData();
                    startActivity(writePatientData)
   }
```

Then, to retrieve the value on another activity:

```
String newString;
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        newString= null;
    } else {
        newString= extras.getString("SYSTEM");
    }
} else {
    newString= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("SYSTEM");
}
```